# Encrypt and decrypt in SWIFT

Tags: swift, encryption, base64, md5, ecb

Im searching for encrypt and decrypt code in SWIFT.

But I cannot found a solution in SWIFT. I need pass a key to encrypt/decrypt in **MD5** and convert to **BASE64** in ECB mode!

I have this code in C#:

```
public static string MD5Cripto(string texto, string chave)
{
  try
  {
     TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider sObCripto 
                      = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
     MD5CryptoServiceProvider sObjcriptoMd5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
     byte[] sByteHash, sByteBuff;
     string sTempKey = chave;

     sByteHash = sObjcriptoMd5.ComputeHash(ASCIIEncoding
                     .UTF8.GetBytes(sTempKey));
     sObjcriptoMd5 = null;
     sObCriptografaSenha.Key = sByteHash;
     sObCriptografaSenha.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;

     sByteBuff = ASCIIEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes(texto);
     return Convert.ToBase64String(sObCripto.CreateEncryptor()
                    .TransformFinalBlock(sByteBuff, 0, sByteBuff.Length));
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
     return "Digite os valores Corretamente." + ex.Message;
  }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

I try this but still not working.. What Im doing wrong? (Ignore my prints..)

```
func myEncrypt(encryptData:String) -> NSData?
{
   let myKeyData : NSData = ("mykey" as NSString)
                     .dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
   let myKeyDataMD5 = "mykey".md5()
   let sArrayByte = myKeyDataMD5.hexToByteArray()
   let myRawData : NSData = encryptData.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!

   let buffer_size:size_t = myRawData.length + kCCBlockSize3DES
   let buffer = UnsafeMutablePointer<NSData>.alloc(buffer_size)
   var num_bytes_encrypted : size_t = 0

   let operation:CCOperation = UInt32(kCCEncrypt)
   let algoritm:CCAlgorithm = UInt32(kCCAlgorithm3DES)
   let options:CCOptions   = UInt32(kCCOptionECBMode + kCCOptionPKCS7Padding)
   let keyLength = size_t(kCCKeySize3DES)

   let Crypto_status: CCCryptorStatus = CCCrypt(operation, algoritm, 
           options, sArrayByte, keyLength, nil, 
           myRawData.bytes, myRawData.length, buffer, 
           buffer_size, &num_bytes_encrypted)

   if Int32(Crypto_status) == Int32(kCCSuccess)
   {
      let myResult: NSData = NSData(bytes: buffer, length: num_bytes_encrypted)
      print("buffer")

      let count = myResult.length / sizeof(UInt32)
      var array = [UInt32](count: count, repeatedValue: 0)
      myResult.getBytes(&array, length:count * sizeof(UInt32))

      print(array)

      free(buffer)
      print("myResult")
      print(myResult)

      let resultNSString = NSString(data: myResult, 
                    encoding: NSUnicodeStringEncoding)!
      let resultString = resultNSString as String
      print("resultString")
      print(resultString)
      let sBase64 = toBase64(String(resultString))
      print("sBase64")
      print(sBase64)

      let data : NSData! = resultNSString
                    .dataUsingEncoding(NSUnicodeStringEncoding)
      let count2 = data.length / sizeof(UInt32)
      var array2 = [UInt32](count: count, repeatedValue: 0)
      data.getBytes(&array2, length:count2 * sizeof(UInt32))
      print("array2")
      print(array2)

      return myResult
   }
   else
   {
      free(buffer)
      return nil
   }
```

}

Comment: Please format your code so it fits without scrolling.

Comment: MD5 is a (weak) hashing algorithm not an encryption algorithm.

Comment: I cannot edit without loose the formatting code! And I know that hash is weak but I need to use that way, that code is used in other versions of app in C#, Android and VB6.

Comment: Yes you can! Check out other code Java questions.

Comment: I clear the code but still scrolling...

Comment: Very close, you just need to break up return line.

Comment: @H.Cardoso Now that we have the formatting out of the way. Stack Overflow is not a code translation service. Volunteers try to help others with problems and simply write code for them.

Comment: @ArtjomB. I don't expect that! I like to know how I use encrypt in SWIFT by MD5 hash passing a key, like i do in C#.

Comment: 3DES, MD5, ECB mode, great combination—for an attacker. Wondering why security is not the top priority when employing encryption.

Comment: There are Swift encryption samples using Common Crypto here on SO. search for them. Make a best effort attempt and if there are problems add that code to the question.

Comment: sometimes in life we just obey the choices of others... there is not MY choice! I found solutions using CommonCrypto and CryptoSwift. Im not a lazy developer but the result of these examples were not what I need.

Comment: It is best to avoid using CryptoSwift, amoung other things it is 500 to 1000 times slower than Common Crypto based implementations. Apple's Common Crypto is FIPS certified and as such has been well vetted, using CryptoSwift is taking a chance on correctness and security. Additionally a US Encryption Registration (ERN) must be optained.

Comment: @H.Cardoso "sometimes in life we just obey the choices of others" even if it results in weak security? Is that what professionals do? Do not use ECB mode, it is insecure, see [ECB mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Electronic_Codebook_.28ECB.29), scroll down to the Penguin.

Comment: @zaph I really tried to explain it but when the owner of the company decides to do this ...

Comment: No problem, there is no requirement in software development to be or behave as a professional. As an example: a civil engineer is a professional and would not use smaller beams that necessary for safety even if his boss told him to. Consider that it is the users who are at risk from poor security, they expect and deserve good security. We can act as professionals or we can as as code monkeys, it is a choice.

Comment: @zaph I really do not know how you work but I know how I work. I never ceased to be professional, much less am code monkey, much less'm still waiting for a response heaven's coming! As anyone expect a little respect as I am giving you respect independent of the choices of others. As the developer first learned to respect my superiors and their decisions despite not agree with many of them and try to alert them about it but this is out of my reach and I have responsibilities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example question code updated.
Not sure what the output formatting code in the question was trying to accomplish.

Note that the 3DES uses a 24-byte key (`kCCKeySize3DES` is 24) and MD5 provides a 16-byte (`CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH` is 16) result so there is a mis-match in key length.

```
func encrypt(dataString:String, keyString:String) -> NSData?
{
    let keyData = md5(keyString)
    let data : NSData = dataString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
    var numBytesEncrypted : size_t = 0
    var encryptedData: NSMutableData! = NSMutableData(length: Int(data.length) + kCCBlockSize3DES)
    let encryptedPointer = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>(encryptedData.mutableBytes)
    let encryptedLength  = size_t(encryptedData.length)

    let operation:CCOperation = UInt32(kCCEncrypt)
    let algoritm:CCAlgorithm = UInt32(kCCAlgorithm3DES)
    let options:CCOptions   = UInt32(kCCOptionECBMode + kCCOptionPKCS7Padding)
    let keyLength = size_t(kCCKeySize3DES)

    let status: CCCryptorStatus = CCCrypt(operation, algoritm, options,
                                          keyData, keyLength,
                                          nil,
                                          data.bytes, data.length,
                                          encryptedPointer, encryptedLength,
                                          &numBytesEncrypted)
    if Int32(status) == Int32(kCCSuccess) {
        encryptedData.length = Int(numBytesEncrypted)
    }
    else {
        encryptedData = nil
    }

    return encryptedData;
}

func md5(string: String) -> [UInt8] {
    var digest = [UInt8](count: Int(CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH), repeatedValue: 0)
    if let data = string.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
        CC_MD5(data.bytes, CC_LONG(data.length), &digest)
    }
    return digest
}
```

Test:

```
let dataString = "Now is the time"
let keyString  = "mykey"
let encryptedData = encrypt(dataString, keyString:keyString)
print("encryptedData: \(encryptedData!)")

let encryptedBase64 = encryptedData!.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions())
print("encryptedBase64: \(encryptedBase64)")
```

Output:

> encryptedData: 8d88a2bc 00beb021 f37917c3 75b0ba1a
>   encryptedBase64: jYiivAC+sCHzeRfDdbC6Gg==

Note:

> 3DES, ECB mode and MD5 are not recommended and should not be used in new code, instead use AES, CBC mode with a random iv and PBKDF2 respetively.

Comment: This function is given always different data, how can I decrypt this?

Comment: @PiyushSanepara That is not clear, ask a new question with a [mcve] and a description of the problem .

Comment: @zaph, I m facing this error in swift-4
Error: **Expression type 'UnsafeMutableRawPointer' is ambiguous without more context**
@ Line of code **let encryptedPointer = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>(encryptedData.mutableBytes)** Can you please give any solution?